# Indexing/Binning Time Series

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a dataframe like bellow

```
    ID    Date
    111   1.1.2018
    222   5.1.2018
    333   7.1.2018
    444   8.1.2018
    555   9.1.2018
    666  13.1.2018
```

and I would like to bin them into 5 days intervals.
The output should be

```
ID    Date       Bin
111   1.1.2018    1
222   5.1.2018    1
333   7.1.2018    2
444   8.1.2018    2
555   9.1.2018    2
666  13.1.2018    3
```

How can I do this in python, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `groupby` + `ngroup` does it:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date, errors='coerce', dayfirst=True)
df['Bin'] = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='5D', key='Date')).ngroup() + 1
```

```
df
    ID       Date  Bin
0  111 2018-01-01    1
1  222 2018-01-05    1
2  333 2018-01-07    2
3  444 2018-01-08    2
4  555 2018-01-09    2
5  666 2018-01-13    3
```

---

If you don't want to mutate the Date column, then you may first call `assign` for a copy based assignment, and then do the `groupby`:

```
df['Bin'] = df.assign(
       Date=pd.to_datetime(df.Date, errors='coerce', dayfirst=True)
   ).groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='5D', key='Date')).ngroup() + 1

df
    ID       Date  Bin
0  111   1.1.2018    1
1  222   5.1.2018    1
2  333   7.1.2018    2
3  444   8.1.2018    2
4  555   9.1.2018    2
5  666  13.1.2018    3
```

Comment: Thank you very much @coldspeed. Did not know about ngroup. I really appreciate your fast answer!

Comment: Worth noting `ngroup` is only available in v.0.20.2+ (released Jun17).

Answer (score 0):

One way is to create an array of your date range and use `numpy.digitize`.

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True)

date_ranges = pd.date_range(df['Date'].min(), df['Date'].max(), freq='5D')\
                .astype(np.int64).values

df['Bin'] = np.digitize(df['Date'].astype(np.int64).values, date_ranges)
```

Result:

```
    ID       Date  Bin
0  111 2018-01-01    1
1  222 2018-01-05    1
2  333 2018-01-07    2
3  444 2018-01-08    2
4  555 2018-01-09    2
5  666 2018-01-13    3
```